# What's a good tool to run SQL scripts against any database?

Tags: sql, database, scripting, database-agnostic

Currently I have a custom tool which generates vanilla-SQL (only using standard SQL), from our Data-models that sets up database schemas and initial data for our new databases, and do version patches, etc... This part is all fine and dandy right now.

However running these SQL scripts against all the different databases (different vendors) is a pain, so I wrote up a quick little Php script a while back that does it for me, but I was wondering if there is any better solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html), it's really cool.

It runs in any plataform (is a Java application), you could connect to any database vendor and it's free.

Comment: Yes I use SQL Developer too, but I though it only supported Oracle and Access... are there plugins or something like that?

Comment: I think you can connect to ODBC datasources?  That would allow you to access almost all databases, and even stuff like Excel sheets and flat files.

Comment: This is sounding better by the moment, but are there any tutorials?

Comment: Look http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/files/featurelist_1_5.htm#con . You can use it with other DB engine, some ones are not supported, but you can use it too. And here is some documentation http://sqldeveloper.solyp.com/download/index.html .

Comment: At the bottom of this page you can found some configuration doc http://sqldeveloper.solyp.com/screenshots/index.html . The tool use jdbc drivers to connect.

Answer (score 2):

I use [**Squirrel**](http://www.squirrelsql.org/), like SQL Developer it is a java application which is free.

**Description**

> SQuirreL SQL Client is a graphical
>   Java program that will allow you to
>   view the structure of a JDBC compliant
>   database, browse the data in tables,
>   issue SQL commands.

[**Download and Installation**](http://www.squirrelsql.org/#installation)